# Please identify microchip with 8 pins as in the picture

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification, components, surface-mount

[image: like this]

It is written on the outer cover as shown in the photo.

Comment: The logo looks like Analog Devices.

Comment: yes please provide me with datasheet matching with  the written on the outer cover as shown in the photo

Comment: Just send the pic to Analog Devices support?

Comment: also, in your previous question, you were pointed at a reference for how to ask good identification question; context matters, you provide none.

Comment: You are consistently asking low-quality questions. Let alone the behaviour not accepting the answers provided by the community.

Answer (score 3):

The logo you've drawn looks a lot like that of Analog Devices.
[image]

[Analog Devices ADP3336](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/ADP3336.pdf) is an 8-pin IC with package marking "L22"
[image]